# How to load assign an image from url to cocos2d control using swift?

Tags: facebook, swift, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am trying to figure out how to load an image via it's url (think facebook profile picture) in a cocos2d game. Can someone help me? I'm using swift but have no idea how to get this image displayed on the UI. Here is what I have so far...

```
 if let currentUserName = PFUser.currentUser()!["profilepic"] as? String {
        if let url = NSURL(string: currentUserName) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){


            }
        }
```

Comment: get an UIImage object (as per @FrequentlyMatched's answer), then use the CCSprite ctor  spriteWithCGImage with the `image.CGImage`. Sorry for my bad swift, i dont speak that semantic sugar coat yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if let profilePic = PFUser.currentUser()!["profilepic"] as? String {
        if let url = NSURL(string: profilePic) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
                   imgView.image = UIImage(data: data!) //where imgView is your UIImageView
            }
        }
 }
```